# update column, table-normalization

Tags: sql, function, procedure

i have a table like:

| name | location |
| --- | --- |
| Emma | Athens |
| Nick | Berlin |
| Emma | Athens-Greece |
| Nick | Berlin, Germany |
| Emma | 233 Street, Athena |
| Nick | Berlin's |

at first, i want to change all values like '%Athen%' to 'Athens' and the same for Berlin
my problem is that my table is full of values like that and it's big , so i wonder if there is a way to do it faster without writing every city-case, such as using functions like substring or creating a function with general forms of my data.
I mean that i don't want something like:

```
update Person  set city='Athens' where city like '%Athen%'
```

i have to have one name for the same city because, about the above example, it's the same emma who lives in athens and the same nick who lives in berlin, so i have to normalize my table to see only one time each person from each city.

Comment: Perhaps you can chose each users _shortest_ location? (Will not handle Athens vs. Athena. But how could we know which one to keep in that case?)

Comment: How can the algorithm distinguish that the 3 rows belong to root substring `Athen` and other 3 rows belong to `Berlin` rather than all 6 rows belong to root substring `e`? You should definitely provide richer data sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a simple solution that means you don't have to check every value. The way I would do it would be:

1. Create a distinct list of every unique location value
2. Put this distinct list in column 1 of a 2 column "lookup" table
3. In the second column put the "clean" version of the value in column 1
4. Write a query that will update the values in your source table based on the values in your lookup table

Having the data in a table, rather in some form of complex SQL CASE statement, makes the information much easier to maintain and the SQL to update your source table much simper